# Using a Load Balancer to route traffic for a RDS in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

Is there a way to use a Elastic Load Balancer to point to a RDS in a private subnet?

Comment: An Elastic Load Balancer cannot "point" to an Amazon RDS server. It only handles web traffic. Or are you referring to a Network Load Balancer? Anyway, aside from that, the general answer is yes, an Elastic Load Balancer in a public subnet can send traffic to resources (eg Amazon EC2 instances) in a private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

No. From a elastic load balancer you can only route traffic to the ec2 instances. Yes these instances can be in a private subnet.